# WingIDE no autocompletion for my modules

Tags: python, ide

If anyone using WingIDE for their python dev needs:
For some reason I get auto-completion on all the standard python libraries (like datetime....) but not on my own modules.
So if I create my own class and then import it from another class, I get no auto-completion on it.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer, it has to do with pythonpath:
http://www.wingware.com/doc/edit/how-analysis-works